# GhostScript output files with original file name

Tags: ghostscript

I'm converting a PDF file to separate images using this command:

`-sDEVICE=jpeg -o page-%02d.png X.pdf`

This outputs the files as:

`page-01.jpeg, page-02.jpeg`, and so on.

However, I want to output the files with this file name:

`X-page-01.jpeg, X-page-02.jpeg`, and so on.

Is it possible to do this with GhostScript?

Answer (score 1):

Well yes, clearly its possible:

```
-sDEVICE=jpeg -o X-page%02d.jpeg X.pdf
```

(I presume that you actually meant page-%02d.jpeg, rather than .png, since you are specifying the jpeg device).

No, Ghostscript won't automagically prepend the input filename to the output filename, you have to do that yourself.

Comment: Couldn't you use a for loop or something? After searching for nearly an hour here, I've come to the conclusion that it might be possible, though I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Ghostscript doesn't allow you to use the input filename in any meaningful fashion. If you want to write a shell script then yes, you can do all sorts of things, but that depends very much on the OS in use, which you haven't mentioned, or given any clues about.

Comment: Well, okay, that's right -- I use Windows. But wouldn't it be almost like asking someone to write the command for me if I asked it that way? I'm not sure that's allowed here.... and personally I don't want to learn how to do it for just this once (that's why I was searching for a solution that would help)

Comment: Make a batch file (eg test.bat) , in it put "gswin32c -sDEVICE=jpeg -o %~n1-page%%02d.jpeg %1" Then call the batch file with the input filename. For example test sample.pdf will then produce files of the form sample-page1.jpeg, sample-page2.pdf etc. You may have to specify a full path to Ghostscript of course, if it isn't in your PATH.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion! I'll try it out and let you know how it goes.